# Xcode Crashing When Opening Project File

Tags: xcode, ide, cappuccino, objective-j

Xcode keeps crashing on me when I open my project file. I've been able to open it fine for weeks now. Not sure how to diagnose. It only crashes for a specific project.

```
Process:         Xcode [1293]
Path:            /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.Xcode
Version:         3.2.5 (1760)
Build Info:      DevToolsIDE-17600000~5
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [189]

Date/Time:       2010-12-15 16:05:24.659 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.5 (10H574)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          201 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  80 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4
Anonymous UUID:                      2B7F7CFC-45EA-450C-8467-6BF1E356B6F6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000025940
Crashed Thread:  10  Dispatch queue: com.apple.Xcode.index-access

Application Specific Information:
objc[1293]: garbage collection is ON
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The crash is generally a sign the project file has been corrupted. Here's a list of possible things you can do to try to fix it.

### 1. Fix a corrupted `*.pbxproj` file

#### Caused by a merge conflict

If you are using version control, it might be caused by a merge conflict that has not yet been resolved.

1. Using Finder, open the directory that holds your project.
2. Right click the project file `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj` and `Open With` your preferred text editing tool such as Sublime Text.
3. Look for merge conflicts which are usually marked using a series of `=========` bars.
4. Resolve the merge conflicts manually or remove the changes of one side.

#### Caused by unreadable XML

If that fails go into the file and quickly scroll through to see if anything seems out of place - it should generally be readable XML.  You could even try an XML validator against it to see if anything amiss was found.

### 2. Reset your workspace

1. Using Finder, open the directory that holds yor project.
2. Right click the project file `MyProject.xcodeproj` and choose `Show Package Contents`.
3. Delete the `xcuserdata` folder, which should contain a folder with your username on it.
4. Repeats step 2 and 3 for your workspace file `MyProject.workspace`

*As elaborated by [KennyWinker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196358/kenny-winker) and [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) on the answers below.*

### 3. Recreate your Xcode project

*Note that this should be your last resort as it is quite tedious to do for large projects.*

Lastly you could simply re-create it.  That might seem like a big pain, but basically you could just create a new project and drag everything under the "Classes" folder into Xcode to start using it (don't forget to also add the frameworks you need).

Comment: Recreating the project file (project.pbxproj) should be a last resort - before that try: quitting Xcode completely, delete build folder, delete username.* files in project.xcodeproj directory, then re-launch Xcode.

Comment: Deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` solved it for me

Comment: The `xcuserdata` deletion fixed it for me, but only when I removed both `MyApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata` and `MyApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata`. So don't forget to dig right inside `MyApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/` and delete that one as well :)

Comment: yeah I had a xcuserdata directory in my xcworkspace, deleting this fixed the issue.

Comment: xcuserdata AND xcshareddata

Comment: Solved deleting xcuserdata of xcworkspace folder. Thanks alot!

Comment: Before recreating the Xcode project, one more thing to do is manually deleting _xcworkspace_ and _Pods_ folder than run `pod deintegrate` then `pod cache clean --all` and `pod install`. This solved it for me

Comment: Deleting xcuserdata worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Solution 2 is working for me with XCode12

Answer (score 102):

Just wanted to elucidate on @Paul R's comment.

I had a situation where Xcode was crashing every time I opened a project file. It seemed to be connect to the IB window that was opening. In the end it was deleting the contents of `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/` that solved this. It did this by resetting the workspace (open files, window scaling, etc.)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: (Surprised that TWFM [this worked for me] isn't in the vernacular.) Anyway, newbies may be interested to know that one exposes the contents of objects such as MyProject.xcodeproj by Control-clicking in Finder and choosing Show Package Contents.

Answer (score 45):

**What worked for me?**

The only solution that worked for me was deleting the derived data folders of the hanging project, i.e the derived data folders in above directory: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`. Hope it helps someone.

**What didn't?**

As mentioned at other places, deleting `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/` or `MyProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/` didn't work for me.

Comment: Both solution didn't worked for me..Still getting crashing again and again.

Comment: This worked for me but the project scheme had to be edited for my simulators and physical device to show up in the Run devices. The executable which was previously set to Myapp.app was set to none.

Answer (score 18):

Just wanted add some extra content to @Kenny Winker answer...

To delete your xcode user data go,

- Find your Xcode project file ex: `MyProject.xcodeproj` or `MyProject.xcworkspace`
- Right click on it and choose `Show Package Contents`
- Finally, just delete everything inside the folder `xcuserdata`
- Done! :)

Hopefully, this adds a bit more context to people who doesn't know where to find their project user data.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem with Xcode 8.1. The reason maybe the `project file contains merge conflict data.`
You can remove this by `opening Xcode project file in TextEdit.`

However, in my case there was no merge conflict. Simply **deleting content of DerivedData worked for me.**

*`Steps :`*

1. Open finder window then select `Go Tab -> Go to Folder… (or press Cmd + shift + G)`

[image: Screenshot 1]

2. Enter `~/Library` and press `Go`. This opens Library folder which is hidden by default.

[image: Screenshot 2]

3. Go to `Developer -> Xcode -> DerivedData` folder. `Delete all the content of this folder.`
   The DerivedData is like cache i.e. create every time you build/run your app.

[image: Screenshot 3]

4. Now open the project. It should work with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

Copying Answer of @Sean D which worked for me.

After seeing a suggestion here, I solved this issue by deleting Xcode's preferences. The most reliable way to do that is the following terminal command, issued after quitting Xcode:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

ETA: Other suggestions have involved changing or removing certain individual preference settings, but after trying a few of those, none worked for me. There seem to be multiple incompatibilities in the preferences between 6 and 7b3, so trashing the prefs entirely should work around them all.

Answer (score 3):

I did every solution on the thread. But nothing helped me. Don't know why.

Instead of opening the project through Xcode, I opened the project through the terminal using `open Project.xcworkspace`, it magically works.

Comment: This worked for me too. I do not understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me, and it was some sort of versioning issue that I couldn't fix, so I reverted back to a prior version and it worked. Feels like there are a few bugs in XCode 4 that still need to be worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your project folder find projectName.xcodeproj or projectName.xcworkspace if you have installed pods right click on it and click on (Show package contents) and finally delete everything inside xcuserdata folder 
Launch your project it will work fine

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same issue, I did every things like below but didn't work for me!

**Deleting the derived data:**

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

**Delete everything inside the folder xcuserdata:**
MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
and
MyProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/

### What worked for me?

In my case I have reinstalled Additional Component(Additional downloads)  from below link then solved this issue.
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/

Answer (score 1):

I had XCode crashing every time I opened Images.xcassets. The solution was to delete a corrupt PDF file I had just added.

Answer (score 1):

**Computer restart**

**worked** for me. While

```
xcuserdata deletion
```

and

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

**didn't work** for me.

I even was not able to open xcode alone or any of my projects or single .m file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any open swift file in a new window (for example when you double click on a .swift file in xCode and it opens in a new window) when xCode opens this might be an issue. I think I had this window opened when closing xCode, then when opening xCode this window opens up again and for some reason crashes xCode. Try to close that open window quickly before it crashes. Strange, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i tested a lot of ways but after of all i just and only change the directory of my project location every thing fixed and my Xcode works properly and I'm glad now....

Answer (score 0):

I experienced XCode crashing when trying to edit a specific original.m file. None of the above solutions worked, but this did:

1. Create a new .m file as new.m for example.
2. Using a text editor open up original.m outside XCode, copy contents and paste into new.m inside XCode. Go back to working in XCode.
3. Delete and move to trash the original.m
4. Rename new.m to original.m
5. Now I can edit original.m without XCode crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were two windows, one on the internal screen of my MacBook and one on an external each with several tabs opened before Xcode crashed and kept crashing on trying to open the `xcworkspace` file. The above mentioned solutions did not work. After disconnecting the external display, Xcode started without crashing and both windows were placed on the MacBook's screen. Reattached the display and everything worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

I you use Cocoapods try pod deintegrate, delete the workspace, then pod install. This cured it here (Talking of Xcode 11.2.1 after upgrading the Mac to Catalina and the following crashing Xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Towards a cocoa pods included project, I resolved this issue by renaming workspace file and running "pod install" on terminal again.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, everytime xcode was crashing. i restarted mac, cleared derived data/xcuserdata but nothing worked.

I had one more repo so i copied 'project.xcodeproj' file from there and paste it in current repo, this trick resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project -> right click on .xcodeproj -> show package contents -> delete all files in xcuserdata.
Quit the xcode -> reopen

Delete the [image]

Answer (score 0):

Open project in previous version of Xcode and then close it and reopen it on Xcode version that you are using for project,
suppose you are using Xcode 11.1 and it is getting crashed while opening projects, then open it in Xcode 10.0 or 10.1.

Answer (score -1):

1. Fix a corrupted *.pbxproj file
2. Reset your workspace
3. defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

do 1~3 and

```
git clone ~~~.git newGitProject
```

**copy** MyProject.xcodeproj, MyProject.xcworkspace

go to GitProject

**paste** MyProject.xcodeproj, MyProject.xcworkspace

worked for me.

if you have git repository , try it ;)