# ios - moving frameworks broke the project

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I recently added the Social.framework and Accounts.framework to my ios project. It was placed on top of the navigator area and I dragged those two into the frameworks folder.  Then it showed in red color in the Build Phases "Link Binary with Libraries" ....and now the project crashes on startup.

What did I do so wrong? And what is the correct way to fix this?

I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
  Referenced from: /Users/owner12/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/823A0485-7443-4206-B9F5-A84C03DBFB89/BusinessPlan.app/BusinessPlan
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong. Sometimes Xcode gets confused. I would suggest that you edit the project, scroll down to where it lists the frameworks, and select the Social and Accounts frameworks and click the Minus button.

[image]

After that, you might want to quit Xcode and clean out the build folder as described here:

[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

If *that* doesn't solve it, you might have to revert to an earlier commit.

Comment: Also there is a very helpful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9494112/341994 Sometimes the project file is corrupted and you have to open it and get rid of the user settings

Comment: thank you - the first solution didn't quite work so I am going to try now your second suggestion. I also posted my error in my original question

Comment: The error message tells us that the reference is still in there. Did you clean the derived data folder *and* delete the app from all simulators and devices??

Comment: I tried different variations of your original suggestions and then it worked :)

Comment: I know, sometimes you have to keep hitting Xcode on the side of the head.

Comment: Thank you - you have helped me many times with my iOS adventures.  Do you have apps of your own?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28853/discussion-between-genadinik-and-matt)