# Xcode 5 crashing all the time when trying to open a particular project

Tags: xcode, xcode5

When I try to open a particular projects target settings in xcode 5 it crashes. When I try to open it in Xcode 4 versions its fine.

[Screen Shot http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9527/kiew.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/9527/kiew.png)

Comment: If Xcode crashes please file a bug (at very least send the crash report). If you can append the project to your bug report.

Comment: Before filing a bug make sure all your software is up to date!

Comment: @HAS I have filed a bug report. But the project is working before I have played with image catalog assests after that only I am getting the above issue. I have to send build to customer but I couldn't proceed because of this.

Comment: Do you use the latest Xcode? I remember there were problems with assets in the betas.

Comment: @HAS Yes its XCode 5, latest version

Answer (score 0):

This got fixed with today's update to the OS. I am using OSX Mavericks!. Make sure to update.

Good luck!

Comment: Not yet fixed am using mountain lion tried so many times installing uninstalling but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Reverting project file changes and resetting the workspace worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494112/974531