# XCode 8.1 crashes when I open .swift/.xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, xcode8

I had previously installed XCode 7.3 and updated it to 8.1 through the AppStore. When the project opened(XCode 8.1, Swift 3.0, Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6) I'm trying to open any file(.swift/.xib/.storyboard/.plist/.coredata etc.) the XCode just crashes.

Here is the my Crash Log of XCode 8.1: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/339bffc7b67100ae5e82012393cb00bd

Comment: are you using version control for project?

Comment: Clear the derived data folder(~/Library/Developer/Xcode), and also the XCUserData from your Project. kindly make sure you quit all Xcode and then try these steps.I had faced similar issue and these steps did worked for me.

Comment: If nothing else works you can try deleting `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` (when Xcode is quit) it resolves many issues *but* you also lose many preferences that you'll have to set again manually, so use it as a last resort.

Answer (score 7):

Try below steps, it may solve problem:

- Open a Finder window and navigate to your project
- Right-click on the `.xcodeproj` file (it’s a package actually)
- Select Show Package Contents
- New window appears
- Delete a folder called `xcuserdata`

Also, [Clear the derived data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8).

[image: img]

Some helpfull links:

1. http://pinkstone.co.uk/xcode-crashes-every-time-you-open-it-and-how-to-fix-it/
2. [XCode Crashing When Opening Project File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455903/xcode-crashing-when-opening-project-file)
3. [How to add .gitignore file into Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517440/how-to-add-gitignore-file-into-xcode-project)

Comment: For me, Xcode 8.1 started crashing on opening a particular project, this worked great (cleaning derived data in my case was not necessary).

Answer (score 3):

In the Utilities view, put "Top Bar" and "Status Bar"  entries to "None". Temporary fix from Apple.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me and is the advised course of action by Apple.

Comment: is there any advice for those who don't use interface builder ?

Comment: @RodrigoGonzalez Don't have the issue with the 8.2.1 version anymore. Did you try to update your Xcode?

Comment: I updated to the 8.2.1 version yesterday, and this seems to be fixed, I haven't had a crash since then.

Answer (score 0):

Select Xcode and Follow 4 steps that highlighted in photo and remove derived data then restart your project.[image]