# Xcode8.3 constantly crashes after update

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

After update Xcode 8.3 is crashing constantly. At start it was 30 to 40 minutes but today it is crashing after just 10 seconds. Any help will be highly appreciated. Below is crash report.

```
Process:               Xcode [555]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.3 (12169)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-12169000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       821487965
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [555]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-03-29 17:52:50.427 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.4 (16E195)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        C95FFD88-0B61-915D-E373-1F31A265D400


Time Awake Since Boot: 250 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
MainQueue: _compat_sourcekitd_set_notification_handler_block_invoke_2
ProductBuildVersion: 8E162
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-12150/DVTFoundation/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:905
Details:  Path must be absolute but is not: <built-in>
Object:   <DVTFilePath>
Method:   +filePathForPathString:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc33ae02970>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. This is really annoying. I have to revert back to the previous version.

Comment: I observed that Xcode crashes when i open Swift classes . On obj C it does not crash.

Comment: Exact same problem. Always with Swift classes.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning your Xcode's derived data. That seemed to solve the problem for me.
Run this on your terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Comment: it doesn't, unfortunately

Comment: Sad to hear it. Maybe on your situation there is something else causing it. Try to delete derived data, clean the project and maybe remove Xcode cache.

Comment: I did everything I could do, but nothing happen. Just waiting for 8.3.1 :(

Comment: Best of the lucks to you. This is a problem that, apparently, happened in previous versions of Xcode.
Some people suggest deleting Xcode, removing all the files associated with it, and then install it again. Try that. I think Xcode 8.3.1. will take a while to come out.

Comment: I did, everything. Really Thanks

Comment: I also tried this. Deleted xcuserdata as well, completely re-installed Xcode, but nothing helped. Xcode still crashes randomly shortly after some code editing

Comment: What do you mean by "partially"?

Comment: Can you please check if the crash reports the very same issue, or if there is any change to it?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar issue, with Xcode 8.3, and it was crashing shortly after I began to edit my code in any swift files in my project, editing Objective-C files never caused a crash

There are a few steps that seems to help with fixing the issue:

1. Quit Xcode
2. [Delete xcuserdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437297/3065769) folder (Navigate to your project in Finder, right click on `YourProject.xcworkspace`, choose `Show package contents`, then delete `xcuserdata` folder).
3. [Delete DerivedData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)

I'm not 100% sure you need to actually quit Xcode before deleting these though.

Comment: Ugh, although it only seems to help temporarily, Xcode starts crashing again after a while.

Answer (score 1):

[crash info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q28U.png)

I updated to Xcode 8.3 yesterday. Xcode constantly crashes for no reason. I used a lot of methods including: Unloading reloading Xcode, rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/, Shutdown restart mac.

In Xcode8.2 I modified the name of `newWeeklyMissionVC.swift` to `NewWeeklyMissionVC.swift` class and in storyboard.  So I guess after update Xcode8.3, Xcode can't  indexing the storyboard, and cause crash.

So I resolved this by deleting the `NewWeeklyMissionVC.swift` class in the storyboard and Rewrite it. Now Xcode doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: @AlSweigart The post is most certainly attempting to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click project.xcworkspace
2. Show Package Contents
3. Delete xcuserdata folder

Then File > Open > project.xcworkspace and project will open perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.
After installing the pending Mac OS Sierra update, my Xcode is not crashing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I've notice that if you clean project (CMD + SHIFT + K) Xcode doesn't crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I started to have same problem when I added Google Maps reference to my `Bridging-Header.h` file. Once I removed it, it started to work again.

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the caches causing the issue `rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/`

Comment: Ok, so this seemed to solve for about an hour. It doesn't seem to solve it permanently

Comment: I observed that Xcode crashes when i open Swift classes . On obj C it does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

I auso had same problem.(with message "Path must be absolute but is not")

In my case, it's caused by ACEDrawingView Pod.
When I put "import ACEDrawingView" in a swift file, Xcode crash.
Xcode doesn't crash after following step.

1. Remove ACEDrawingView entry from Podfile
2. pod update
3. Download ACEDrawingView source zip from GitHub
4. Add sources to project, and create Bridge-Haeder.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same problem except mine crashed after a few seconds. Only for a particular project. The important bit from my crash report was:

"ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-13231/DVTFoundation/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:883"

I tried everything i could find online, but after looking around for ages, what seemed to work for me was to open Xcode in a different project(or new project) and switch off the Xcode Source Control. Go to Xcode preferences, then Source Control, and then untick 'Enable Source Control'. Then if necessary try restarting Xcode and possibly your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and couldn't open any project. I deleted my derived data and even restarted my mac but it wasn't working.

I ended up creating a new project. Then I was able to switch over to my existing projects.